# When do the enemy villages gain units?

Tags: ninja-village

I'm reaching the point where the opposing villages have hundreds of each type of unit, making it really hard for me to beat them within the 3 day limit.  Most of my fights end up being draws.  At this point, its also super expensive to buy additional units (4k gold per upgrade).  Did I spend too much time doing other things, what determines when villages increase their units?  I'm currently on year 8 if that matters.

Comment: I'm having the same problem; it's sort of hard to chew through 1000 infantry, even without their other forces.

Comment: @fbueckert [this thread](http://adeptgamer.com/forum/threads/a-general-guide-and-direction-for-the-lost-and-worried.594/page-2) has some really nice setups to use, including a way to make over 16k gold per week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the other clans only gain units every time one of them is defeated.  So it helps to save some of the 'weaker' clans and take out the hard ones first.