# When to attack a strong clan?

Tags: ninja-village

When should I attack big clan like Takeda or Tokugawa? I want to defeat them as soon as possible before their army gets massive, but it doesn't seem to be more effective than leaving those clans till last.

Answer (score 1):

Ninja villages only [gain more units when you take over one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112526/when-do-the-enemy-villages-gain-units).

Thus its to your benefit to attack them as early as you can.  However, if the bonus they give you isn't worth it then you should put them off for later.  Tokugawa gives you some great items, but he's the hardest village, so unless you have enough land/units to gain a lot of gold per month to really pump that army, its nearly impossible to defeat him early on, especially since his army has great tech already.

Keep in mind that even if you fail against a village, you'll gain a few units so its almost always worth it to be attacking (unless you can't afford the gold).  There are ways to [layout your village](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115792/how-do-i-increase-my-villages-income-in-ninja-village) to maximize income though.

Comment: I, almost forgot.  Always take the emperor challenge when it respawns.  It costs no gold to do and he gives nifty rewards at certain levels.